# VBS Shell Application Windows doesn't return correct number of IE Tabs

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, vbscript

I am trying to access to the second tab on Internet Explorer 11 with the following vbs code without success:

```
With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows()
  WScript.Echo "Shell windows count = " & .Count
  For z = 0 To .count-1
    WScript.Echo z & " , " & .Item(z).LocationURL
  Next
End With
```

When I programmatically click on "Print" on the Ribbon in the first tab, the second tab will come. The second tab has the same URL with the first tab.

[image]

The code worked properly on 3computers that I can tested but it doesn't on one of my computer. Maybe you guy have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got this by a workaround. I change one tab setting for Internet Explorer:
[image]